# Windows AZURE I/O Tests Temp Drive D: vs Attached Drives

Tags: performance, azure, io, virtual-machine

I am testing the speed of the drives on the Windows Azure VM's Drives. It seems to me like the speed difference between the temporary drive d and the attached drives is huge!

The test I have is running iometer program on

Maximum Disk Size 20 Gigs
16 Outstanding I/O's
4k100% read, 0% random

60seconds Run time

Results: 
Temporary Drive D: Total I/Os per second 60978.94
Drive E (1 30 gig drive): 910.51
Drive F (4 30 gig drives striped together): 899.6

Is this normal?

The reason I am really noticing the difference is in SQL. I basically tried to migrate from my old physical server with sql2000 2 gigs of ram and scsi drives, and that thing is faster than windows azure large image. Faster in that I can run queries about twice as fast.

I turned off diskcaching on os drive in os.

Can someone explain to me what is going on? am I comparing apples to oranges? thanks!

Comment: How long did you run your queries in SQL?  Mark Russinovich mentioned that If you planned on doing metrics to make sure to run your queries for about 45 mins or so before starting to take metrics.  This helps Windows Azure storage recognize the way data is accessed and balance the work more.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is normal. The temp disk is a physical disk on the node (only disk I/O here), and the E/F/... disks are persisted disks. This means they are actually page blobs in blob storage and you'll need to take into account network I/O as well.

To improve I/O and throughput you might consider to disable the cache for those disks (this incurs more transaction costs). Read more about this on the Windows Azure Storage Blog: [Exploring Windows Azure Drives, Disks, and Images](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/28/exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx)